# Problemas en la interpretación de los datos recibidos mediante Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código:
**Clases.php**

```
public function nuevoTicket($folio, $fecha, $id_empleado, $id_dependencia, $id_unidad, $select_com, $select_prov, $litros_comb, $total_ticket) {
    sleep(1);
    try {

        $this->Conectar_BD();
        $this->query = "INSERT INTO control (fecha, id_empleado, id_dependencia, id_unidad, id_combustible, rfc_proveedor, folio_ticket, total, litros) VALUES (str_to_date(?, '%d-%m-%Y'),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
        $this->consulta->bind_param('ssiiisidd',$fecha,$id_empleado,$id_dependencia,$id_unidad,$select_com,$select_prov,$folio,$total_ticket,$litros_comb);
        if ($this->consulta->execute()) {
            //Si se hace correctamente imprimimos true
            $this->obtenerGasto($id_dependencia,$total_ticket);
            echo "true";
        } else {
            //Si no imprimimos false
            echo "false";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "false";
    }
```

**Script.js**

```
function nuevoTicket(folio, fecha, id_empleado, id_dependencia, id_unidad, select_comb, select_prov, litros_comb, total_ticket) {
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Folio: folio, Fecha: fecha, Id_empleado: id_empleado,
        Id_dependencia: id_dependencia, Unidad: id_unidad,
        Combustible: select_comb, Proveedor: select_prov,
        Litros: litros_comb, Total: total_ticket,
        Funcion: 'Nuevo-Ticket'},
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#nuevo-ticket").fadeOut('slow').show();
        $('#admin-gif').fadeIn('slow').show();
    }
})
        .done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data === "true") {
                $("#nuevo-ticket").show();
                $('#admin-gif').hide();
                $('#admin-success-tk').fadeIn(200).show();

                $('#folio-ticket').val("");
                $('#fecha-ticket').val("");
                $('#id-empleado').val("");
                $('#select-dependencia').val("");
                $('#id-unidad-ticket').val("");
                $('#select-comb').val("");
                $('#select-prov').val("");
                $('#litros-comb').val("");
                $('#total-ticket').val("");

                $('#admin-error-tk').hide();
                $("#admin-gif").hide();
                $('#campos-vacios').hide();

                todosTickets();
            } else {
                $("#nuevo-ticket").show();
                $('#admin-gif').hide();
                $('#admin-error-tk').fadeIn(200).show();
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
            $("#nuevo-ticket").show();
            $('#admin-gif').hide();
            $('#admin-error-tk').fadeIn(200).show();
        });
}
```

El problema que estoy teniendo, es que los `echo` de php a la hora de ser recibidos por mi `.done` del `Ajax` y me genera algunos conflictos visuales.

[image: Imagen 1]

> En la imagen muestro que si estoy obteniendo el valor **true** de mi petición.

Pero en la comparación, no es interpretado de una forma correcta, provocando que me muestre lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje que debiera mostrar en cuanto a color y texto son diferentes, pero en la comparación no se interpreta como debiera ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que tu cadena ¿`"true "`?  o ¿`" true "`?  o ¿`" true "`? ... venga con espacios de más o algo así. Suele ocurrir.

Puedes probar a hacer la comparación, limpiando el dato con `trim`:

```
if (trim.data === "true") {
    //... resto del código
```

¿Y si PHP decide que no es una cadena, sino un booleano y lo devuelve como tal? Entonces la comparación de tipos `===` fallará y en consecuencia deberías probar así:

```
if (trim.data == "true") {
    //... resto del código
```

En cualquier caso, no puedes dejar que decidan por ti, no puedes escribir un código que luego tengas que limpiar. Es mejor escribir algo más coherente...

---

### Un consejo, para evitar esto

Sugeriría que escribas un código coherente. Si vas a trabajar con un valor booleano, entonces usa variables booleanas propiamente, no una cadena.

Por ejemplo, en el PHP puedes tener una variable `$bolStatus` establecida a `FALSE` por defecto. La misma sólo cambiará si ocurre algo en el `try`.

También, en Ajax es mejor trabajar con respuestas del tipo JSON. A veces, por diversos motivos, trabajar con texto, puede provocar que tu cadena sea devuelta con espacios en blanco y cosas así... `true  <un espacio` no es lo mismo que `true`.

Aquí es muy importante el `header` que hay en la penúltima línea.

### PHP

```
public function nuevoTicket($folio, $fecha, $id_empleado, $id_dependencia, $id_unidad, $select_com, $select_prov, $litros_comb, $total_ticket) {
    sleep(1);
    $bolStatus=false;
    try {

        $this->Conectar_BD();
        $this->query = "INSERT INTO control (fecha, id_empleado, id_dependencia, id_unidad, id_combustible, rfc_proveedor, folio_ticket, total, litros) VALUES (str_to_date(?, '%d-%m-%Y'),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
        $this->consulta->bind_param('ssiiisidd',$fecha,$id_empleado,$id_dependencia,$id_unidad,$select_com,$select_prov,$folio,$total_ticket,$litros_comb);
        if ($this->consulta->execute()) {
            //Si se hace correctamente imprimimos true
            $this->obtenerGasto($id_dependencia,$total_ticket);
            $bolStatus=true;
        } 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            //Aquí si quieres puedes meter otra clave si deseas mostrar
            //en el cliente el error que ha ocurrido
    }

    $arrRespuesta=array('status'=>$bolStatus);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    print_r(json_encode($arrRespuesta));
```

### JS

En el JS tendrás que hacer dos pequeños cambios, dejando todo lo demás como está:

Aquí, indicas un `dataType` para la petición:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',

    //... resto del código
```

Y modificas un poco la forma de leer la respuesta, ya que PHP te devolverá un objeto JSON así:

```
{"status":true}
```

O bien:

```
{"status":false}
```

Entonces, en el `done` tendrías que acceder a la clave `status` de `data` y como es un booleano lo puedes evaluar así `if (data.status){` :

```
   .done(function (data) {
        alert(data.status);
        console.log(data);
        if (data.status) {
           //... código 
        }else{

           //... código                     

        }
```

Comment: desconozco muchas funciones de javascript y JQuery, gracias por el aporte, me sirve aprender cosas nuevas.